# Jenkins + Apache with mod_proxy

Tags: apache, jenkins, lets-encrypt

I have an AWS EC2 instance running, with only port 22 and 443 as inbound security rules.

**Jenkins Configuration**

```
in file -->> /etc/default/jenkins
HTTP_PORT=8080
NAME=jenkins
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --prefix=/jenkins"
```

**Apache Configuration**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

            ServerAdmin email@domain
            ServerName subdomain.domain.dev
            ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.dev

            DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.domain.dev

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins nocanon
            ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins
            ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://subdomain.domain.dev/jenkins
            ProxyPassReverse /jenkins https://subdomain.domain.dev/jenkins
            ProxyRequests     Off
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

            RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
            RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

            <Proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins*>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Proxy>


            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf        
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.dev/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.dev/privkey.pem

    </VirtualHost>
 </IfModule>
```

ports.conf

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

With the above configurations, when I try to go to https://subdomain.domain.dev/jenkins it gives a 403 and then redirects to https://subdomain.domain.dev/login?from=%2Fjenkins where it gives a 404 error.

Apache Access Logs

```
162.158.227.119 - - [20/May/2023:17:09:38 +0000] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 403 5890 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
162.158.227.119 - - [20/May/2023:17:09:39 +0000] "GET /login?from=%2Fjenkins HTTP/1.1" 404 525 "https://subdomain.domain.dev/jenkins" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

There are no errors being logged in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Running `sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` gives the following output

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  subdomain.domain.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subdomain.domain.dev-le-ssl.conf:2)
```

Also, I am using Cloudflare with Full Strict SSL/TLS and used letsencrypt to generate the SSL Certificate.

OpenSSL Version `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)`

Adding screenshot of the redirect from the browser
[image: Redirect]

**Resources**

1. [Jenkins Official Reverse Proxy Configuration Apache](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-with-jenkins/reverse-proxy-configuration-apache/)
2. [How to Setup Jenkins with SSL with Apache Reverse Proxy on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-setup-jenkins-with-ssl-with-apache-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu/)
3. [Install and Configure Apache as Reverse Proxy for Jenkins](https://rimsovankiry.medium.com/install-and-configure-apache-as-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins-3fb860924a53)
4. [Apache reverse proxy config with SSL for Jenkins and Sonar](https://serverfault.com/questions/653408/apache-reverse-proxy-config-with-ssl-for-jenkins-and-sonar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to get this working, though I am not sure if this was the actual solution or just a coincidence.
I first stopped apache, then did a `sudo apt remove --purge jenkins`.
After that, reinstalled Jenkins and updated the `/etc/default/jenkins` file with the correct prefix and the *httpListenAddress* which was *127.0.0.1*.
Then after a reboot of the instance itself, I was able to get Jenkins up and running. Have been running and configuring Jenkins for almost a day now, no issues found thus far.
In any case, I am not satisfied that I have actually *solved* anything. If anyone knows the root cause of this, please let me know.